# Texture unwrapping seems wrong

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to do do something very simple: texture a simple (non-uniformly scaled) cube. I started with one face, the up face, but it doesn't seem right; I don't know how to explain it. Take a look:

[image: The cube's up face selected]

On the left, the cube's up face sits perfectly on top of the black dots and lines, but on the right, they seem off. Why is that? What I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it?
I'm new to Blender.

Comment: Hello, could you please pack your image and share your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: "Non uniformly" like the sides are not the same size? Because that could be the problem

Comment: @moonboots Too late :(. I removed that "cube" and started all over again and I didn't have this problem again.

Comment: @Emir Yes, the sides were not the same size, but I solved that problem by applying Ctrl+A -> Scale.